# How to use get function in mailbox systemverilog

Tags: system-verilog

I am a beginner in systemverilog and I tried to make a complex code used to compare between two mailboxes 
and it gives me these errors in simulation
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9NdJl.jpg)

//the package code
     package types;
      typedef struct{
      int pid;
       }packet;
        endpackage
        //the main code

```
     module mbox;                                                       
    import types::*;                                                 
    //Declare two mailboxes here                                       
    mailbox exp_mb = new(256);             
      mailbox act_mb = new(256);                                            
            // This task supplies stimulus to the two mailboxes           
               task stimulus();                                         
       packet stim_pkt;                                                    
       for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++) begin
stim_pkt.pid = i;

//*** Write stim_pkt to both mailboxes here
exp_mb.put(stim_pkt);
act_mb.put(stim_pkt);
$display("Sending pkt: ",i);                                               
     end                                                                      
       endtask                                                              
         // Add task checker here                                         
         task check(input mailbox exp_mb ,act_mb);                         
             bit com;                                                   
     packet x;                                                          
    packet y;                                                              
    for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++) begin                                  
       x.pid = exp_mb.get(i) ;                                           
       y.pid =  act_mb.get(i);                                             
     com = compare(x,y);                                                    
        if (com == 1)                                                 
           $display ("No Error");                                         
            else                                                      
     $display ("Error in %d", i);                                          
           end                                                         
         endtask                                                            
       // Add function compare here                                   
       function bit unsigned compare (packet a ,b);                         
     if (a.pid == b.pid)                                                
    return 1;                                                             
          else                                                          
          return 0;                                                
            endfunction// Add an initial block to run stimulus & checker tasks simultaneously    
       initial                                                           
       begin                                                              
       fork                                                        
          stimulus();                                             
        check(exp_mb ,act_mb);                                       
       join_none                                                           
       end                                                           
          endmodule
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message tells you exactly what the problem is. The mailbox `get()` method does not return a value, it places a value in its argument.

I believe you want

```
exp_mb.get(x) ;                                           
act_mb.get(y);
```

Also, A good idea is add types to your mailboxes. Will become very helpful in getting compile errors instead of runtime errors as your code grows and the number of different packet types grow.

```
mailbox #(packet) exp_mb = new(256);
mailbox #(packet) act_mb = new(256);
...
task check(mailbox #(packet) exp_mb ,act_mb);
```

Comment: Hello, Dave!
I want to get the data from exp_mb and act_mb mailboxes and compare them in compare function

Comment: The answer I gave does what you ask.